# Tikz - Perform mathematical operations on label names

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use variables for labels in Ti*k*Z.

Let us say we want to have 3 points *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, *x*<sub>3</sub> (I am searching a general solution with *n* points, but for simplicity 3 is sufficient) on the same line.

Further we want to draw a line between *x*<sub>1</sub> -- *x*<sub>2</sub> and one between *x*<sub>2</sub> -- *x*<sub>3</sub>.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
            \node[draw] at (\x, 1)   ({\x}) {Label \x};

            \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
                \draw[] (\x) -- ({\x+1});
                                  ^^^^^^
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

What should I write instead of `\x + 1`?

I tried with the `{}`-parenthesis and with `\pgfmathparse{\x + 1}\edef\storeresult{\pgfmathresult}`

Comment: How about `\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using {int(\x+1)}] in {0,...,2}
                \draw[] (\x) -- (\y);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two more solutions. (`chains` is only required for the second solution.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
  \node[draw] (\x) at(3*\x,1){Label \x};
  \draw[] (0) foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using {int(\x-1)}] in
  {1,...,3}{(\x) -- (\y)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
  \node[draw,on chain,join] (\x) {Label \x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

one solution among others:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
            \coordinate(\x) at (3*\x,1);

            \draw[] (0) foreach \x in{1,...,3}{-- (\x)};

            \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
            \node[draw, fill=white] at(\x){Label \x};

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]